# How to set a dynamic expression name at runtime (JSON Parser)

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, javascriptserializer

I'm building a JSON file parser. I currently use the JavaScriptSerializer class to read the JSON file into a DynamicJsonObject that looks like

```
dynamic glossaryEntry
```

Then I can retrieve top level json nodes in the following manner. For retrieving this JSON group called Scoring that looks like

```
{
    "Scoring":
    [
        {
            "blah": "blah",
            "blah": "blah"      
        },
        {
            "blah": "blah",
            "blah": "blah"      
        }   
    ]
}
```

I use the dynamic expression:

```
return glossaryEntry.Scoring;
```

Or for instance I'd use

```
return glossaryEntry.quests;
```

For a JSON that looked like:

```
{
    "quests":
    [
        ... 
    ]
}
```

Which is very hardcoded and requires me to know in advance all possible identifiers that can be parsed. I am thinking there must be a way to have that dynamic expression evaluate to something so that the glossaryEntry."this" part can be determined at runtime?

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your json string to `Dictionary<string,object>`

```
var glossaryEntry = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var keys = glossaryEntry.Keys.ToList();

var scoring1 = glossaryEntry["Scoring"];
//OR
var scoring2 = glossaryEntry[keys[0]];
```

Comment: I may be missing something but the issue is that the dynamic object will always use the variable name and not its value... So returning glossaryEntry.scoring2 will still search the value "scoring2" and no the value of keys[0]?

Comment: You should use like this `glossaryEntry[keys[0]]` or `glossaryEntry["quests"]`

Comment: You were right, I actually had to leave the glossaryEntity alone, just returning the scoring1 or scoring2 variables gives me the same value that glossaryEntry.quests would have given. Fantastic. Thanks so much! (the code that worked is actually the one previous to the modifications you made, i.e. var scoring1 = dict[keys[0]]

Comment: (the code that worked is actually the one previous to the modifications you made, i.e. var scoring1 = dict[keys[0]])

Comment: In fact I just renamed `dict` to `glossaryEntry`